# Puppet: I try get memory fact in mainifest and get error Operator '[]' is not applicable to an Undef Value

Tags: puppet

I would like to get memory in bytes and I use this code in manifest

`$memoryforapp = $facts['memory']['system']['total_bytes'] * 0.7`

but I have got this error message

`Error: Operator '[]' is not applicable to an Undef Value.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first run on a new server, Puppet doesn't have fact `total_bytes` but has these memory facts:

```
memoryfree
memoryfree_mb
memorysize
memorysize_mb
```

Then we can calculate memory in bytes. I want to know 75% value

`$memoryforapp = ceiling(($::memorysize_mb * 1024) * 3/4)`

Comment: Glad this worked out- please mark the questions as resolved if they are resolved- it's fine to mark your own answer as resolved.